# how access list of object inside a list of object in c#

Tags: c#, list, hierarchy

This is a teacher objects

```cs
List<Teacher> teachername = new List<Teacher>();

Teacher teach = new Teacher();

teachername.Add(new Teacher("malathy", 2341, 987452165,0));
teachername.Add(new Teacher("shobhana", 3432, 4512789,1));
teachername.Add(new Teacher("indira", 6432, 243254564,2));
```

This is students object

```cs
teach.studentlist.Add(new Student("manu", 1, "babu",2341));
teach.studentlist.Add(new Student("anu", 1, "sabu", 2341));
teach.studentlist.Add(new Student("hiba", 2, "vasu", 3432));
teach.studentlist.Add(new Student("shuba", 2, "gopi", 3432));
teach.studentlist.Add(new Student("indu", 3, "soman",6432));
teach.studentlist.Add(new Student("indira", 3, "Raman", 6432));
```

I want to separate and control the students by its numbers,ie,the 1 numbers students are under teacher malathy.2 number students are under shobhana.

Comment: Is the 4th element of `Teacher` objects supposed to be equivalent to 2nd element of `Teach`  object?

Comment: How does the `Teacher` class look like? And `Student` class? What are the parameters you use in the constructos? What is `teach` and `studenList` (should be an uppercase `StudenList` btw)? (Yeah, i could guess and would probalby right, but post all info needed to help you or else its just, well, guessing)

Comment: I know this may seem a trivial subject, but I think bad naming convention *becomes* a matter when you want to explain your code to others, expecially in an international environment like this (I am a non-English native speaker). Variable names shoud reflect what those objects represent: you have a list of teachers, why call it `teachername` instead of `teachers`? And why "students object" starts with `teach`? Naming is the first means to understanding.

Answer (score -2):

```
var MalathysStudents = studentlist.Where(s=>s.TeacherId==1).ToList();
```

Comment: no need to convert from enumerable first